# Issues working with complex.h

Tags: c

I have written a small c code to find the sqrt of a number . And i want the program to even find the sqrt of a negative number . I came across complex.h and couple of functions to perform the complex arithmetic .I have made use of them and i'm getting a couple of warning messages while compiling.The code does not calculate the square root of positive and negative numbers correctly .

1)What is  the correct format specifier for printf and scanf for printing and taking in complex numbers ?
Please let me know where exactly i'm going wrong .I'm using a gcc compiler and OS is Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.I have attached the code and the outputs.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <complex.h>


    int main()
    {
      float complex var,op;
      printf(" Enter the number : " );
      scanf("%lf",&var);
      op=csqrt(var);
      printf("%lf \n",op);
    }

    o/p Enter the number : 4
        0.011604
    Another o/p Enter the number : -4
        -0.011604
```

Comment: *Undefined behavior*, the format doesn't match the argument. `%lf` expects a `double *`. You need to scan real and imaginary parts separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the square root of a negative number you can use the following code,

```
  printf(" Enter the number : " );
  scanf("%lf",&var);
  if(var < 0)
  {
     op=csqrt(-var);
     printf("The square root is %lfi \n",op);
  }
  else
  {
     op=csqrt(var);
     printf("The square root is %lf \n",op);
  }
```

Comment: i have done the above method to find the square root of positive numbers using sqrt function. But it gives nan as output for negative numbers . I want to write a  code which calculates the  roots of both negative as well as positive  numbers .

Answer (score 2):

From C99:

> 6.2.5/13 Types
>
> Each complex type has the same representation and alignment
>   requirements as an array type containing exactly two elements of the
>   corresponding real type; the first element is equal to the real part,
>   and the second element to the imaginary part, of the complex number.

So as one possibility, you can use:

```
scanf("%f %f",&var[0], &var[1]);
```

To read in a `float complex` type, with whitespace separating the real and imaginary parts.

Answer (score 1):

`printf` and `scanf` don't have native support for complex numbers, but that's OK; you can write the format easily enough:

```
scanf( "%f %fi", &re, &im );
```

now `re` and `im` contain the real and imaginary parts (although it won't accept spaces after the `+` or `-`, so `3 + 2i` will be rejected, but `3 +2i` and `3+2i` are fine.

The same goes for printing;

```
printf( "%f%+fi", re, im );
```

will print the variables in `3+2i` form.

Finally, though it doesn't seem to be directly part of your question, the square root of a negative number is simply the square root of the positive value multiplied by `i`.

Comment: Thanks Dave. It does solve my problem.I'll try to explore more on this .